# Newton's Disc rotation program too slow. Any way to speed up timer? Also, animation flickers. Any way to fix that?

Tags: java, performance, animation, timer

I want to make a program in Java to rotate a Newton's Disc at high speed so that it appears white. But the timer class has a minimum delay of 1 millisecond only. Can I speed things up somehow (maybe I can pass something like 0.084 as delay somehow?)? Also the image flickers. Any way to get rid of it? Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class NDisc extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
Timer a;
double angle=0;//To store value of angle of rotation in radians
ImageIcon c;
Image dbImage;
Graphics dbg;
public NDisc()
{
a=new Timer(1,this);//Change delay here to increase or decrease the speed of rotation
c=new ImageIcon("ND4.png");
a.start();
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
super.paintComponent(g);
g2.rotate(angle,300,300);//300,300 is the center of the screen which I need as the point about which the disc rotates
c.paintIcon(this, g2,100,100);//Image dimensions in (300,300) and JFrame size in main() is (600,600), so I paint the image at (100,100) thus making the center of the JFrame and the image coincide 
angle+=0.001;//To increment angle of rotation for the animation to take place
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
repaint();
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
NDisc obj2=new NDisc();
JFrame obj=new JFrame("Physics");
obj.add(obj2);
obj.setSize(600,600);
obj.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
obj.setResizable(true);
obj.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Most animation is at around 23 frames per second. NTSC is 30. Progressive display is 60. There are 1000 milliseconds in a second. Please explain why you think you need sub-millisecond precision? Finally, use double buffering (`setDoubleBuffered(true)`) in your `NDisc` constructor to resolve your flicker.

Comment: Whan you properly indent your code, I'll give you 10 reps (that's a single upvote). The way it's now, it's hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

You've got it wrong. For an animation you really need no more than ~25 fps. What you need is to adjust the work done between animations.

Simply replace

```
angle+=0.001;
```

by something configurable and you're done.  But let's do it better:

```
angle = speed * System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
```

This works even when you can't keep the pace given by the timer. The disadvantage is that you can't stop the time. But this has a simple solution, too (ask if you need it).